# python pytest asyncio sqlachemy asyncsession: testing two identical tests the first one passed but the second test failed

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pytest, python-asyncio

I am trying to test a simple async function which gets a user object from a postgres database when given an email address (*get_user()* in *user.py* below).

The function itself works fine and the test was working too (*test_get_user_one()* in *test_user.py*). However, when I made an identical test *test_get_user_two()*, the new test failed with the following error message:

```
...
...
>               self._write_fut = self._loop._proactor.send(self._sock, data)
E               AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

C:\Python\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py:397: AttributeError
================================ short test summary info ===========================================
FAILED test/test_user.py::test_get_user_two - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
================================ 1 failed, 1 passed in 1.02s =======================================
```

When *test_get_user_two()* and *test_get_user_one()* swap places, the _two() passed and _one() failed with the same error.

Please could someone point me to the right direction as what causes this problem? Thanks!

*session.py*

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

async_engine = create_async_engine("postgresql+asyncpg://url", echo=False,future=True)
async_session = sessionmaker(async_engine,class_=AsyncSession,expire_on_commit=False)
```

*user.py*

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from model import User

async def get_user(email: str, session: AsyncSession) -> User:
    query = select(User).filter(User.email == email)
    async with session:
        results = await session.execute(query)
        user = results.scalar_one_or_none()
        return user
```

*test_user.py*

```py
from session import async_session
from user import get_user

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_user_one():
    user = await get_user(_email, async_session())
    assert user.email == "user@email.com"

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_user_two():
    user = await get_user(_email, async_session())
    assert user.email == "user@email.com"
```

Edit: the **User** object comes from *model.py*

```py
from typing import List, Optional
from pydantic import EmailStr
from sqlmodel import Column, Field, Relationship, SQLModel, String

class UserBase(SQLModel):
    email: EmailStr = Field(sa_column=Column("email", String, unique=True))

class User(UserBase, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    lastname: str | None
    firstname: str | None
```

Comment: I can't get past `from model import User`.  Where is that supposed to come from?

Comment: added model.py for the User object... thanks.

Comment: Now I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'NoneType'`.  Maybe I'm missing something obvious, I'm not much of a sqlalchemy user.

Comment: There isn't such an error for me, could it be due to a different version of sqlalchemy? But those lines are not important, can even be removed: `lastname: str|None` and `firstname:str|None`.